# Multiple swagger documents with Spring Boot - for different http operations

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui

I figured that there is a way to group endpoints into different swagger documents, but i wanted to know if there is a way to separate endpoints based on get/post/patch operations?

For eg, i have 2 endpoints

```
Get : /app/employee
Post: /app/employee
```

How can i segregate them into 2 different swagger documents?

Edit 1 : I am referring the below article to segregate swagger endpoints in spring boot:
https://dev.to/s2agrahari/grouping-apis-in-swagger-55kk

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your questione answered by **using tags**?

Here is the [Official example](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/grouping-operations-with-tags/).

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

In your `application.yaml`, you can configure like this:

```
springdoc:
  swagger-ui:
    operationsSorter: method
    enabled: true
    tags-sorter: alpha
```

Reference: https://swagger.io/docs/open-source-tools/swagger-ui/usage/configuration/

Also there is a question with more details for setting it programatically: https://swagger.io/docs/open-source-tools/swagger-ui/usage/configuration/

Answer (score 0):

You gave the answer partially yourself, you can just do:

```
@Bean
GroupedOpenApi getApis() {
    return GroupedOpenApi.builder().group("My Get Apis").addOpenApiCustomiser(customizer()).build();
}
```

And then some logic (maybe you have double check it, but something like so):

```
public OpenApiCustomiser customizer() {
    return (OpenAPI openApi) -> {
        final List<String> keysToDelete = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Map.Entry<String, PathItem> entry : openApi.getPaths().entrySet()) {
            if(entry.getValue().getGet() == null) {
                keysToDelete.add(entry.getKey());
            }
        }
        keysToDelete.forEach(key -> openApi.getPaths().remove(key));
    };
}
```

And the same for Post or any other Rest operation....